# Visual Studio 2010 crashes nearly every time when closing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crash

Mostly it happens if we open a team project from tfs 2008 or tfs 2010, but crashes can happen any time.

When VS is closing down, it crashes nearly every time.

Tried trial RTM and our MSDN download - same story. Tried on three different PCs - same issue. Tried on 32 and 64-bit Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 - crashes.

Is it just our luck or does it happen to you to?

Comment: doesnt happen to me. and yes the comments below are very funny

Comment: What 3rd party addins do you have loaded?  Does it happen without a project loaded or does it happen with the same project or different projects?

Comment: No addins, no extra program. Vanilla OS, cleanly installed VS 2010 premium.

The crashes are obviously caused by TFS: when a team project is open and the IDE is being closed, it crashes immediately.

Comment: You should probably file a bug on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: I don't have connection to TFS, and the project is not in source control. It crashes EVERY time I try to close some file, window. Really really annoying, i'm switching now back to VS2008

Comment: It's bloody irritating!  Corrupted a few solution files which has caused no end of grief.  Embarrassing that at this stage in the product's 'maturity' (TFS being a v3 product now) that this kind of thing made it into the RTM version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged it as an issue on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/585343/team-explorer-vs-2010-crashes-on-close).

There is a new release of the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) and [Visual Studio 2010 Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) which seem to reduce the instances of VS crashing (although it still seems to crash from time to time).  It might be worth checking out if you use either add-in.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips that will hopefully help you identify the problem:
http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/02/08/how-to-investigate-and-report-visual-studio-issues.aspx

Ideally, get a call stack of the devenv.exe main thread with symbols loaded, and post it here (or even better), attach to the Connect bug. From the stack we'll likely be able to tell what kind of problem it is.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the crash was caused by using a DNS name in Connect to Team Foundation Server.

I replaced that with the IP address of the TFS server and the crashes went away.

We have two Windows Server 2003 DNS servers, and it looks like Visual Studio 2010 does not communicate with them correctly. Visual Studio 2008 connects to the TFS without any issues.

Comment: I tried this as well, but it still crashed - albeit, not as frequently :(

Comment: How does one change this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there a bug:

"Large Visual Basic project crashes when closed"

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=29797

Comment: lol - I had to reinstall my system and here I am a second time to discover that I could not upvote this a second time.